# HTML book style paging

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have an unusual task. I have a big html with images and links. I need parse it and show as book with book style paging (by swipes). Do someone faced with task similar in iOS? Maybe there exist an opensource ebook solutions (with HTML support)? For example in Android I used FBReader.

I need iOS native solution.

Comment: Not whats the best way to paginate it (probably server side), however this is a really good library to detect swipes -> http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Answer (score 0):

You have [turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/), but it's not free

And [jQuery booklet](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/), but this one doesn't include swipe

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for native code you can get the paging effect from the following example 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-an-ipad-reader-for-war-of-the-worlds/